# Nuclear Reaction Conservation of Nucleons

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm having a hard time trying to understand a nuclear reaction:

$$_{2}^{1}\textrm{He} + {}_{3}^{6}\textrm{Li} \rightarrow 
{}_{\phantom0 5}^{10}\textrm{B} \rightarrow {}_{4}^{9}\textrm{Be} + {}_{1}^{1}\textrm{H}$$

Why in the second step of the equation is $10$? instead of $7$? if you add the subscripts in both sides they need to be equal. The conservations of nucleons are $1 + 6 = 10$ and in the conservation of charges are $2 + 3 = 5$ however int the third step this is right, $10 = 9 + 1$ and $5 = 4 + 1$. So how does this work?

Comment: $_{2}^{1}\textrm{He}$ this can't be right. In general you have: $_{Z}^{A}\textrm{X}$, where $Z$ gives the number of protons and $A$ gives the number of nucleons (protons + neutrons). In $_{2}^{1}\textrm{He}$, you already have $2$ protons, so $A$ cannot be less than $2$.

Comment: It should bei $^4_2 He$; not $^1_2 He$.

Comment: I made a tricky editing to your equation. If you don't like it, you may cancel it.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to have the element $_2^1\text{He}$. This is because the atomic number (the bottom number) is the number of protons in the nucleus, and the mass number (the top number) is the number of protons and neutrons in the nucleus, so the top number must always be greater than or equal to the bottom number. Most likely this is a typo and is meant to be $_2^4\text{He}$.